# AWS Lambda Typescript function: How to transpile and packaging dependencies with SAM?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm currently working on an AWS Lambda function that I've written in typescript with the following folder structure:

```
my-lambda-function/
  ├── src/
  │   ├── handler.ts
  │   └── utils/
  │       └── helper.ts
```

I have been trying to build the function using 'Sam Build' to package the function for deploying.

My template.yaml is using the following structure for the function:

```
handlerFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Handler:src/handler.Handle
...
```

I've been using the tsconfig.json template that is provided by AWS:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "strict": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "module":"commonjs",
    "moduleResolution":"node",
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "isolatedModules": true, 
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

However when I run the Sam Build command, the resulting build artifacts folder looks like the following:

```
build/

  └── handlerFunction/
      ├── handler.js
      └── handler.js.map
```

The handler typescript is transpiled into javascript as seen above however the node modules and the helper.ts file are not included so when I run sam build., The handler.js file imports the helper.ts library so without it it fails to run.

Is this possible to include these dependencies (node modules and this helper.ts) through editing the template.yml or do I need to transpile the files individually and create a zip then upload it manually (not ideal), surely there is a way to build this properly and deploy using sam?

I've tried editing both template.yml and the tsconfig.json but have had no luck. I'm not sure if there is a property that I missing. Could my folder structure be the issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update on 2023-03-08

Using a single package.json with AWS SAM is not a default behavior, but you can make it work. I created a working example in GitHub.

- https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/aws-sam-nested-applications-single-package-json

### Original answer

From the SAM build documentation:

> By default, SAM will look for a dependency manifest (ex: `package.json`) at same folder containing SAM template.
>
> If a --root flag is set, we will look for manifest at this folder.
>
> If neither locations have a manifest, we will look for a manifest
> within the folder containing function code.
>
> Manifest present within the code folder always overrides manifest at the root.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/blob/develop/designs/sam_build_cmd.md

If your SAM template file is in a different folder from the `package.json`, you can use `--manifest` when running `sam build`:

```
sam build --manifest ./package.json
```

https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/4427#issuecomment-1344815721

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The package.json is found when I run sam build from the root directory. However, it doesn't get built into the handlerFunction build artifact folder, the sam build process completes without error but the handlerFunction folder only contains handler.js, handler.js.map, and nothing else, no node modules and helper.ts doesn't get transcribed either. Sorry I'm quite new to Lambda, the package.json and template are both in the root directory, should they be in the src folder with the handler.ts before I build?

Comment: The `CodeUri` property of your template.yaml is where your package.json should be. For example, if you have `CodeUri: functions/my-lambda` you need a package.json inside the "my-lambda" folder. This AWS blog post can help: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-typescript-projects-with-aws-sam-cli/

Comment: Using a single package.json with AWS SAM is not a default behavior, but you can make it work. I created a working example in GitHub: https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/aws-sam-nested-applications-single-package-json